# Starting program on boot with screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

Here is my script in init.d (Debian Linux)

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/blah
#

# Some things that run always
touch /var/lock/McMyAdmin

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
start)
echo "Starting McMyAdmin "
screen -dmS Minecraft
sleep 2
screen -S Minecraft -X stuff "bash /opt/McMyAdmin/start.sh"`echo -ne '\015'`
;;
stop)
echo "Stopping McMyAdmin"
screen -S Minecraft -X stuff "\quit"`echo -ne '\015'`
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/McMyAdmin {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac

exit 0
```

My problem is that upon starting the screen session, nothing happens. If I type line by line it works fine, but in the script nothing works. It creates the screen session but no commands are sent to it. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to cd to the McMyAdmin installation directory before you can run it. You can't run its start.sh script from another directory.

Change:

```
screen -S Minecraft -X stuff "bash /opt/McMyAdmin/start.sh"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

to

```
cd /opt/McMyAdmin/
screen -S Minecraft -X stuff "sh start.sh"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

Also it's not a brilliant idea to put McMyAdmin in /opt/ and running it as root. Instead you should create a user just for it and use either a @reboot line in that users crontab, or use su in your initscript to change which user is used to run the server.

Comment: That dosen't seem to do it. Its the weirdest thing. It seems like I cannot send a command to the screen inside the script. I cannot send anything. This would work fine outside the script.